# Which months in Japan lowers probability of natural disaster?

Tags: japan, safety, natural-disasters

I want travel Japan but it gets earth quakes, tsunamis, typhoons. Which months for lowest probability of these natural disasters?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Typhoons hit Japan mostly between May and October with the peak in August and September. They can make landfall anywhere in Japan, but not all do. About seven each year pass over Okinawa, while only three reach the main islands. Later storms are generally more powerful than earlier ones.

Earthquakes are unpredictable and can occur at any time and be of any strength. Tsunamis are caused by earthquakes and are similarly unpredictable. Most earthquakes are small and just result in a few seconds of gentle shaking at most. This might be unnerving to someone unused to them, but they cause no damage. Large earthquakes and tsunamis are rare.

Japan is well prepared for all three events. Only in exceptional cases is there any significant threat to safety.